# My program is really simple but my fps doesn't increase more than 20

Tags: python, pygame

I started making a game and thought its frame rate was 60 fps. After I found a way to display the true frame rate, I saw that it was actually on the order of 20 fps. I made a simpler version of the program that should definitely run at 60 fps, but to my surprise it also ran at 20 fps. When I ran my game on another computer, it ran at 60 fps as I expected. Why would it run on one computer at 20 fps and another at 60 fps?

This is the simpler version of my program:

```
import pygame as pg
import sys

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 800
FPS = 60

BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pg.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False


    pg.display.set_caption(str(clock.get_fps()))

    screen.fill(BLUE)
    pg.display.update()

pg.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your game ran how it should on a different machine, the problem most likely exists in the machine you were having problems with, and not your code. I am no expert in this field, but you should check your machine settings because I believe there are settings that control the maximum/minimum FPS on a computer.

Comment: Thanks but i also have to mention on the other computer, the frame rate had sudden falls